# Flutter: Making clipped area transparent for scrolling ListView

Tags: flutter, listview, clipping

I have a `ListView` that I would like to "disappear" when it hits the clipping of another widget.

Here is my code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          TopWidget(),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView(
              itemExtent: 100,
              children: <Widget>[
                Card(color: Colors.green,),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TopWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  TopWidget();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomPaint(
      painter: ShadowPainter(),
      child: ClipPath(
        clipper: TopWidgetClipper(),
        child: Container(
          height: 370,
          color: Colors.blue,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TopWidgetClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    Offset controllPoint1 = Offset(0, size.height - 100);
    Offset endPoint1 = Offset(100, size.height - 100);
    Offset controllPoint2 = Offset(size.width, size.height - 100);
    Offset endPoint2 = Offset(size.width, size.height - 200);
    Path path = Path()
      ..lineTo(0, size.height)
      ..quadraticBezierTo(
          controllPoint1.dx, controllPoint1.dy, endPoint1.dx, endPoint1.dy)
      ..lineTo(size.width - 100, size.height - 100)
      ..quadraticBezierTo(
          controllPoint2.dx, controllPoint2.dy, endPoint2.dx, endPoint2.dy)
      ..lineTo(size.width, 0);
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) {
    return true;
  }
}

class ShadowPainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Offset controllPoint1 = Offset(0, size.height - 100);
    Offset endPoint1 = Offset(100, size.height - 100);
    Offset controllPoint2 = Offset(size.width, size.height - 100);
    Offset endPoint2 = Offset(size.width, size.height - 200);
    Path path = Path()
      ..lineTo(0, size.height)
      ..quadraticBezierTo(
          controllPoint1.dx, controllPoint1.dy, endPoint1.dx, endPoint1.dy)
      ..lineTo(size.width - 100, size.height - 100)
      ..quadraticBezierTo(
          controllPoint2.dx, controllPoint2.dy, endPoint2.dx, endPoint2.dy)
      ..lineTo(size.width, 0);

    canvas.drawShadow(path, Colors.grey[50], 3.0, false);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

So far, when I am scrolling down, the list (green box) goes unseen when it reaches the bottom of the container (yellow border) of my clipped `TopWidget`. But I would like the list to smoothly disappear only when it reaches the edges of my clipping (i.e. the blue area - like in the second screenshot).

[image]

[image]

Any ideas how I could accomplish this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have learnt it from @pskink (thanks for that) in use cases like this where you need the widget to actually adjust its boundaries (spoiler: shape) you should make use of the `shape` property of different widgets and use the `Path` you used for this example in a custom class which extends `ShapeBorder`. Easiest approach would be:

```dart
Container(
  height: 370,
  decoration: ShapeDecoration(
    color: Colors.blue,
    shape: AppBarBorder(),
    /// You can also specify some neat shadows to cast on widgets scrolling under this one
    shadows: [
      BoxShadow(
        color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.7),
        blurRadius: 18.0,
        spreadRadius: 2.0,
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

And the custom class:

```dart
class AppBarBorder extends ShapeBorder {
  @override
  Path getOuterPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection textDirection}) {
    Offset controllPoint1 = Offset(0, rect.size.height - 100);
    Offset endPoint1 = Offset(100, rect.size.height - 100);
    Offset controllPoint2 = Offset(rect.size.width, rect.size.height - 100);
    Offset endPoint2 = Offset(rect.size.width, rect.size.height - 200);
    
    return Path()
      ..lineTo(0, rect.size.height)
      ..quadraticBezierTo(
          controllPoint1.dx, controllPoint1.dy, endPoint1.dx, endPoint1.dy)
      ..lineTo(rect.size.width - 100, rect.size.height - 100)
      ..quadraticBezierTo(
          controllPoint2.dx, controllPoint2.dy, endPoint2.dx, endPoint2.dy)
      ..lineTo(rect.size.width, 0);
  }

  @override
  EdgeInsetsGeometry get dimensions => EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 0);

  @override
  Path getInnerPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection textDirection}) => null;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Rect rect, {TextDirection textDirection}) {}

  @override
  ShapeBorder scale(double t) => this;
}
```

Pretty much the same approach how you would declare a `CustomClipper` or `CustomPainter` since you don't need to implement most of those methods and essentially only need to care about `getOuterPath`.

At the end we need to restructure the layout itself, since currently you have a `Column` with this custom `Container` shape and the `ListView` beneath that. Since the `Container` is not part of the `ListView` it can't be scrolled under or something. Easiest approach would be using a `Stack`:

```dart
Stack(
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 370.0),
        itemExtent: 100,
        children: <Widget>[
          Card(
            color: Colors.green,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    Container(
      height: 370,
      decoration: ShapeDecoration(
        color: Colors.blue,
        shape: AppBarBorder(),
        shadows: [
          BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.7),
            blurRadius: 18.0,
            spreadRadius: 2.0,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Comment: wonderful! Thank you so much! I only had to remove the Expanded widget around the ListView, as it threw an exception... otherwise it works perfectly!